# what is difference between req.user and req.isAuthenticated()

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Why use `if(req.isAuthenticated())` instead of `if(req.user)` to check if user is logged in

Comment: Some providers might define a different property, although [`user` is the default](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/a892b9dc54dce34b7170ad5d73d8ccfba87f4fcf/lib/passport/http/request.js#L68-L81).

Answer (score 0):

These will return the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Basically both will give the same result. See the documentation here
[[1](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/a892b9dc54dce34b7170ad5d73d8ccfba87f4fcf/lib/passport/http/request.js#:%7E:text=req.isAuthenticated%20%3D%20function()%20%7B)]. Request.isAuthenticated is checking the user attribute. When U use passport to create session it creates user attribute

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).